# How to control off line composing message saved in database in Ejabberd?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Hi i have installed ejabberd version 16.04.43 in my server, and its working as per my needs still now. And i got an requirement now where i should not store offline composing message in database can you help me out please..!!

User 1 texting User 2 when User 2 is in Online :

```
user 2 receives typing status and message asap.
```

Now user 1 texting user 2 when user 2 is in Offline :

```
So these message are saved in database along with composing message.
```

So what i need is these composing message should not be saved in database, can anyone helpme out?

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the above answer, Other way to achieve the same would be to add the **no-store** tag in message packet.

i.e similar to:

```
<message to='xyz@xyz.com' id='A33sjdks' from='abc@xyz.com/telnet'>
 <body>Sample message body</body>
 <request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
 <no-store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/>
</message>
```

So, any message stanza with **no-store** tag will be ignored while processing store_packet in mod_offline module.

Just for reference adding composing message stanza.

```
<message 
     from='bernardo@shakespeare.lit/pda'
     to='francisco@shakespeare.lit/elsinore'
     type='chat'>
     <composing xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
     <no-store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/>
</message>
```

The above approach can be handy when you wish to store delivery receipt, read receipt but not composing, typing, gone etc stanza.

Comment: While using this am not able to get delivered receipts.

Comment: You should be able to get delivery receipts. no-store tag has nothing to do with it. If still unable to resolve, kindly share the xml that you are sending

Answer (score 0):

```
mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
    store_empty_body: false
```

Added this lines in ejabberd.yml file and i got output as per i accepted.

Kudos to myself.